# How to add a padding around each box in react-native

Tags: react-native

I'd like to have a blank padding around each boxes.
here is my view code:

```
<View style={styles.wrapper}>
  <View style={styles.container2}>
    <View style={[styles.box, styles.box1]}></View>
    <View style={[styles.box, styles.box2]}></View>
    <View style={[styles.box, styles.box3]}></View>
  </View>
</View>
```

And the followings are the styles I've implemented.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container2: {
    flex: .6,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between', //replace with flex-end or center
    padding:10,
    alignItems: 'flex-start' //replace with flex-end or center
  },  
  box: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    padding:10
  },
  box1: {
    backgroundColor: '#2196F3'
  },
  box2: {
    backgroundColor: '#8BC34A'
  },
  box3: {
    backgroundColor: '#e3aa1a'
  },
}
```

As you can see here, I've just got the paddings at each end.
[image]

I'd like to have the padding around each boxes instead.
Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `box: {..., margin: 10}` instead of `padding: 10`

Comment: If this does work tell me to write it as an answer

Comment: @YamanKATBY Thanks for the tip! You can write it as an answer :)

Comment: If my answer was useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also, see stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `margin` instead of `padding`.

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...,
  box: {
    ...,
    margin: 10,
  },
});
```

## What’s the difference between margin and padding in CSS?

> In CSS, a `margin` is a space around an element’s border, while the `padding` is the space between an element’s border and the element’s content.